How do I monitor my app's logs using prometheus?
If an application's log file is modified 300 seconds from the current time, prometheus starts sending email alerts, how should this requirement be implemented?


It looks like you are trying to do a check if app is alive. If that's the case, why not to use more traditional approach with metric up? 2. Prometheus is rarely a correct tool when talking about something related to logs. Do you have log-specific tools (like Loki, for example) in your environment?


I have ELK in my environment.
